# CORS error: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://api.com (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null)

Tags: docker, express, next.js, cors

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://bayut-api-v1:4000/properties/list?purpose=for-sale&locationExternalIDs=5002&sort=city-level-score&location=dubai&page=1. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

I am using docker I built "API" and "FrontEnd with nextjs"  dockerized all of that in a custom network
named "bayut"
and exposed port 80 with Nginx *using Nginx as a reverse proxy

the traffic comes on port 80 -> port 3000 which is the nextjs app

iam getting a cors error when I use the app from localhost
but when I try to use the firefox docker image inside my "bayut" network
everything works perfectly fine

- API: http://bayut-api-v1:4000
- FrontEnd http://client-bayut:3000 ->no cors error when I use this domain inside the bayut network

but  when I access from localhost outside the bayut network iam getting a cors error
one possible solution is to use https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites
but that solution will expose my API and I want my API to privat

I will add my index page on the server side

```
import express from "express";
import { Request, Response, NextFunction, Application } from "express";
import { Server } from "http";
import createHttpError from "http-errors";
const Redis = require("ioredis");
const cors = require("cors");
const client = new Redis({
  port: 6379,
  host: "redis-bayut",
});
// const client = new Redis(6379, "172.17.0.3");

require("dotenv").config();
const app: Application = express();

const allowedOrigins = ["http://bayut-client:3000", "http://localhost:3000" ,"127.0.0.1:3000"];

app.use(cors({
  origin: allowedOrigins,
  methods: ["GET"],
}));
app.get("/", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.send("Hello World3!");
});
// Routes
app.use("/auto-complete", require("./routes/auto-complete"));
app.use("/properties", require("./routes/properties"));
app.use("/agencies", require("./routes/agencies"));
const acceptOnlyGetRequsets = (
  req: Request,
  _res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  if (req.method !== "GET") {
    return next(createHttpError(405, "Method Not Allowed"));
  }
};
//  accept Only Get Requsets
app.use(acceptOnlyGetRequsets);

app.use((req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  next(new createHttpError.NotFound());
});

const errorHandler = (
  err: any,
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.send({
    message: err.message,
    status: err.status,
  });
};

app.use(errorHandler);
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const server: Server = app.listen(PORT, () =>
  console.log(`=>  http://localhost:${PORT}/
  ⌛ ${new Date().toLocaleTimeString("en-us", { timeStyle: "medium" })}
  `)
);

export const redisClient = client;
```

Comment: _"that solution will expose my API and I want my API to privat"_ - You have to expose the API to make client-side requests to it. Add authentication/access control to the API if you want to restrict access to it.

Answer (score 1):

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://bayut-api-v1:4000/properties/list?purpose=for-sale&locationExternalIDs=5002&sort=city-level-score&location=dubai&page=1. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: **(null)**.

This error means that:

- You are making a cross-origin request
- The request failed entirely
- Because it was cross-origin and it failed entirely there is no response so there are no response headers that could include CORS permission to give your JS access to that data.

(I think other things could cause the `null` status, but its pretty clear what it means given the context of the rest of your question).

In short: The browser can't access the URL you gave it.

---

> but that solution will expose my API and I want my API to privat

If you want client-side JavaScript to access the API then you **must** expose the API to the browser.